# Is it possible to execute a script stored within a .jpeg file?

Tags: image, assembly, jpeg

Our finals project in our Ethical Hacking Elective Class requires us to create a .jpeg file with a script that would automatically run when the jpeg is opened. Preferably with the common image viewer but it is okay to mention other image viewing software that might achieve this.

Is this possible?
What programming language should I look into to make this?
I used the tag Assembly as I assume that it might be possible if the image file's code can be altered in that level, but this is just my speculation and I hope that someone can explain if it is so or not.

I have seen some tutorials online about how to hide a .txt file inside an image file and how to disguise a .exe file to look like an image file using WinRar. But I need the file to be in .jpeg format.

I hope I am allowed to do this but here is a link to what I have in mind.
[Security Stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/97856/can-simply-decompressing-a-jpeg-image-trigger-an-exploit)

Comment: As far as I know this usually requires an image viewer with a security flaw (e.g. possible buffer overflows). Maybe you get more response on your question if you submit it to https://security.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Okay. Will submit it there as well now.

Comment: EMU8086 is an 8086+DOS emulator.  I don't think it even HAS a JPEG viewer.  So unless you plan to *write* a JPEG viewer with intentional security vulnerabilities that you can exploit to inject an executable payload into it, this makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry for that, should I just remove the tag and edit the question?

Comment: Well what image viewer *are* you trying to exploit?  "The common image viewer" on what OS?  The default image viewers on the mainstream OSes like Windows, Linux, and OS X don't have known vulnerabilities!

Comment: That 's nice to know but that just means this project is now even harder. I am curious as to which Image Viewer I can use to accomplish this now.

Comment: You could make a .jpg.exe file, but it's effective against people who know this trick

Comment: I think you need to ask your instructor what this assignment was supposed to be about.  A remote code / script execution bug in a JPEG viewer that anyone actually uses would be a *huge* deal.  Is this "ethical hacking" course using a toy / learning environment where there are vulnerable versions of applications with easy to find buffer overflows?  Or are you supposed to approach this completely differently with a file named `.jpeg` but actually containing something else (Linux / Unix), or named `.jpg.exe` for crappy software that hides actual file extension?  i.e. not a JPEG image at all.

Comment: Yeah, honestly the motive to this project is quite shady. But I like how she kinda wants us to do something with that much of a deal. I think I'll pass it even if it's something that can only be done with old systems like Windows XP. I don't think it has to be Windows 10. As long as I can show that it works. My problem really is where to find a reference or how exactly should I go about this.

Comment: I backup other people's comment sand stressing out the need to talk with the instruction. As stated, you are asked to find a 0day. Furthermore, an extremely useful one as images can be embedded in webpage and may potentially be rendered with the same library the default image viewer uses. This may be worth hundreds of thousands of dollars. Considering the average level of the EH courses I've seen this seems implausible. Ask the instructor what this is all about.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. This question belongs on https://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

There two approaches. (1) You'd have to find some Jpeg Decoder with a funkadelic security flaw.

(2) You could create a non-jpeg stream with a .jpeg extension and try to get your operating system to execute it as a script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I've personally created media files that can run JS when included as the `src` of a `<script>` tag. My favorite example is where I took an MP4 of Risk Astley's *Never Gonna Give You Up* and modified it slightly to include JS that would redirect the browser to that video on YouTube if exploited.

Polyglot JPEGs: https://portswigger.net/research/bypassing-csp-using-polyglot-jpegs

Here's an article for GIFs: [GIF/Javascript Polyglots](http://www.thinkfu.com/blog/gifjavascript-polyglots)

Note: a *polyglot* is a program that runs in more than one language.

There are plenty of articles available if you search for "polyglot js image".

Here's a recent one: https://devcondetect.com/blog/2019/2/24/hacking-group-using-polyglot-images-to-hide-malvertsing-attacks

---

So if loading an image via HTML counts as image-viewing software, you're good to go (assuming the HTML loads the image using a script tag, which is not a good idea), but there are plenty of other mediums where such a polyglot could create an exploit.

Comment: If it executed the script when you did `<img src="foo.jpg">` then it would count as image-viewing software, but if requires that you you do `<script src="foo.jpg">` then no it doesn't count as image-viewing software.